# Why does order of `Object.include` and `Fixnum.prepend` matter?

Tags: ruby, module

I have this module:

```
module MyMod
  def +(other)
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

This successfully overrides `+` for `Fixnum`:

```
Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)

123 + :test  # outputs "hello"
```

Let's say I need the `+` operator to be overridden for `Fixnum` and other objects. This successfully overrides `+` for `Fixnum` and other objects:

```
Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)
Object.include(MyMod)

123 + :test  # outputs "hello"
```

But if I change the order of the `prepend` and the `include`, my override has no effect:

```
Object.include(MyMod)
Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)

123 + :test  # error: -:10:in `+': :test can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

Why does the order of `include` and `prepend` have this effect here?

Comment: Oh, incidentally, this is what I used it for: https://gist.github.com/henrik/36b991205d6c772b5a1f#file-pipeline1-rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation of [Module#prepend_features](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features):

> When this module is prepended in another, Ruby calls prepend_features in this module, passing it the receiving module in mod. Ruby’s default implementation is to overlay the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to mod **if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors**. See also Module#prepend.

So, `prepend` only does anything if its argument hasn't already been added to the receiver or one of its ancestors. Since `Object` is an ancestor of `Fixnum`, `Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)` when called after `Object.include(MyMod)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh, so simple. Thank you very much! Will accept your answer in a while when SO lets me.

Comment: Andrian answered you question (+1), but why the rush to select an answer, and why promise to select a particular answer when others (not me) are undoubtedly working on answers? A quick selection may discourage other answers, which, if not better, may still offer interesting observations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I made that statement so Adrian wouldn't need to worry that I e.g. didn't know about accepting answers, since I wasn't able to accept it before a timeout. My "policy" with accepting answers is to accept the first one that answers my question – if a better answer arrives later I'm happy to upvote it (and I did). Is it common to upvote the most detailed answer even if it's not the first one?

Comment: Individual policies for selecting answers seem to vary considerably, ranging from rarely even selecting an answer to always choosing the most helpful answer, even if it is offered years after the question has been asked and after the OP has previously selected an answer. I suggest waiting at least a couple of hours, so as to not discourage other answers and out of respect for those still preparing answers. Beyond that, one can still select the first acceptable answer posted, the most helpful answer, whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify @adrian's answer.

Ancestor chain without modding:

```
puts Fixnum.ancestors
# >> Fixnum
# >> Integer
# >> Numeric
# >> Comparable
# >> Object
# >> Kernel
# >> BasicObject
```

With "working" modding

```
Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)
Object.include(MyMod)

puts Fixnum.ancestors
# >> MyMod # here it is, having precedence over Fixnum#+
# >> Fixnum
# >> Integer
# >> Numeric
# >> Comparable
# >> Object
# >> MyMod # note the second copy. include(MyMod) doesn't check for duplicates, but it doesn't matter (here).
# >> Kernel
# >> BasicObject
```

With "not working" modding

```
Object.include(MyMod)
Fixnum.prepend(MyMod)

puts Fixnum.ancestors
# >> Fixnum
# >> Integer
# >> Numeric
# >> Comparable
# >> Object
# >> MyMod  # fixnum will override this
# >> Kernel
# >> BasicObject
```